# Android: How can I include a Licence.txt file in aar?

Tags: android, aar

I want to include a LICENSE.txt file in my .aar file. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding Gradle Tasks that unzip your aar, copy your License file in it and rezip the aar.

Should be done between 'bundleRelease' task and 'uploadArchives' task

This is how I could do it :

```
android {
    // (...)

    def libraryModuleName = 'your-library-module-name'
    def outputAarDir = rootProject.file(libraryModuleName + '/build/outputs/aar')
    def outputAarUnzipedDir = rootProject.file(libraryModuleName + '/build/outputs/aar/unziped')
    def aarReleaseFile = rootProject.file(libraryModuleName + '/build/outputs/aar/' + libraryModuleName + '-release.aar')

    task unzipAar(type: Copy) {
        from zipTree(aarReleaseFile)
        into outputAarUnzipedDir
    }

    task addLicenseFileInUnzipedAar(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'unzipAar') {
        def fromDir = rootProject.file(libraryModuleName + '/')
        from fromDir
        into outputAarUnzipedDir
        include 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    task reZipAar(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'addLicenseFileInUnzipedAar') {
        from outputAarUnzipedDir
        include '*'
        include '*/*'
        archiveName libraryModuleName + '-release.aar'
        destinationDir(outputAarDir)
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        bundleRelease.finalizedBy(reZipAar)
    }
}
```

Then those tasks are added to your standard build process.

gradle console after a build :

```
(...)
:your-library-module-name:bundleRelease
:your-library-module-name:unzipAar
:your-library-module-name:addLicenseFileInUnzipedAar
:your-library-module-name:reZipAar
```

Comment: I do not have 'bundleRelease' task and 'uploadArchives' task in my gradle file.

Comment: There are standard tasks already provide by gradle/android. How do you generate your aar and distribute your library ? me I'm using maven plugin and so uploadArchives task, but maybe you do this in another way.

Comment: I've edited my answer, this solution also works with simple build task, so should be ok.